# Ticks near origin not rendered in ListPlot

Tags: ticks

```
ListPlot[{{0.5, 0.5}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, {{0., "fail"}, {1., "pass"}}}]
```

The inserted text `"fail"` does not appear at the origin. (At x-coordinate 0.09 it is visible, but at 0.08 it is gone.)

Comment: A crude way would be to add `AxesOrigin -> {0, -0.12}`...

Comment: You could use the `Text` graphics primitive in `Prolog` or `Epilog` to add a text label there.  The position at which a tick gets rendered seems to depend on the plot size, and changes dynamically as the plot is resized with the mouse.  This suggests that the decision not to show it is made by the front end (which renders graphics).

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica does not like to draw tick labels close to the origin of a plot. Suggest you use a frame with frame ticks to solve your problem.

```
ListPlot[{{0.5, 0.5}},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-.5, 2}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{{{0., "fail"}, {1., "pass"}}, Automatic}, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]